# iOS - Swift - Token is not generated at first launch

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, token

It seems that the token is not always generated at the first launch. So `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is not getting called.

This situation rarely happens, why?

Comment: Have you checked for an error using `​did​Fail​To​Register​For​Remote​Notifications​With​Error​` ?

Comment: Did you enable push notification in capability?Implement error delegate and check

Comment: If you're running in the simulator you can't register for remote notifications

Comment: Please provide code. How you request access and when you call registerForRemoteNotifications. I think you call this method before get access.

Comment: it seems that the method application.registerForRemoteNotifications() fails, However, this happens sporadically.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have checked Remote Notifications in background modes. Refer following screenshot for more information.[image]

Comment: You need to use this flag only if you want update content when you receive remote notification. From documentation `The app wants to start downloading content when a push notification arrives. Use this notification to minimize the delay in showing content related to the push notification.`